# Python updating object in list when object updates

Tags: python, list, object, pointers

I have a list where I've created objects then put them in a list but when I update the object itself it doesn't update the object in the list.

Setup Code:

```
class char:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def update(self, age='nil'):
        if age == 'nil': age = self.age
        return char(self.name, age)

Mile = char("mile", age=12)
Pauline = char("pauline", age=14)

chars = [Mile, Pauline]
```

How I update the characters:

```
Mile = Mile.update(age = 16)
```

But then if I get `chars[0].age` it still returns 12 unless I do `chars[0] = Mile`.

My question is: is there any way to to automatically update the object in the list when I update the object itself? I've been searching around but haven't come across an answer yet. I should note that this in renpy (though it's regular python code in renpy so that shouldn't have an effect) and when I use the variable inspector it only shows a single pointer in the list no matter how many objects I put in it.

Comment: You do not update the members of your update in your `update` method - you return a different, new object. Why should the object itself change? You provide a new age for your update method, then you overwrite the provided age with the age of your instance and create a new instance ... you never modify the instance `update` is called with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you really mean to return a new `char` from the `update()` method? Doing that signifies that you want `char` to be a value object.

Perhaps you meant just to update the object:

```py
class char:
    def __init__(self, name, age=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def update(self, age='nil'):
        if age != 'nil':
            self.age = age

Mile = char("mile", age=12)
Pauline = char("pauline", age=14)

chars = [Mile, Pauline]
Mile.update(age = 16)
print(chars[0].age)
```

Output:

```
16
```